# WebKit alternative for on Apple Watch? evaluateJavaScript()

Tags: javascript, ios, webkit, apple-watch, watchos

I have a webpage and I want to interact via JavaScript with it (to get data and to perform input events) that means I want to load the webpage in background.

In iOS i could do this easily with `WebKit` and a webView + the `evaluateJavaScript` Method, but since I want to run this on Apple Watch and the fact that there isn't a WebKit framework for watchOS, I am looking for another way to do this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to run JavaScript code on watchOS at the moment. You should either port the code to Swift/Obj-C and run it natively on watchOS or you have to run the JS code in the iOS app, then send over the evaluated data to the Watch app using the `WatchConnectivity` framework.

Since there is no web browser on watchOS (and most likely there won't be one in the near future either), there would be no point in porting the `WebKit` framework to watchOS, so I suggest you find a permanent alternative for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As of watchOS 5:

> Apple has ported WebKit to watchOS, which opens up a lot of possibilities. You can view web content from your watch.

Source: [Apple introduces watchOS 5 | TechCrunch](https://techcrunch.com/2018/06/04/apple-introduces-watchos-5/)

Comment: How can you actually access it? I cannot find it anywhere in Interface Builder and I can't find a documentation on that either